# iOS - General Stream Error (FTP)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to FTP server using different libraries like **simpleSampleFTP** and **FTPManager** but i am getting "general stream error", my credentials and port are right.

When i try to upload file from proxy local network i can upload file to same server but when outside the proxy local network i get general stream error.

I check on FTP the file is being created the name and extension is right but it remains 0 bytes and then after time out i get error "general stream error".

Have anybody faced the same problem? How can i solve this issue any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem occurred because FTP server is using External IP Address. I have solved this problem by passing manual commands to FTP Server.

Comment: This answer is not clear. Can you please explain your answer "passing manual commands to FTP Server"?