# Failed to connect with FTP over explicit TLS/SSL using objective c

Tags: objective-c, ssl, ftp

I am using "https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager" and trying to connect with "ftp.onehub.com" FTP over explicit TLS/SSL but it always fails to connect and below log prints -

> FTPManager[9987:118563] ftp stream failed: general stream error (check
>   credentials?)

The login credentials are right because it connects with FireFTP, Connection type - Auth SSL or TSL.

Please help.

Comment: may be [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780285/ios-general-stream-error-ftp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780285/ios-general-stream-error-ftp) can help.

Comment: I checked that but the answer is not clear. If you understand that answer, can you please help with "passing manual commands to FTP Server"?

Comment: Unfortunately, can't.